# Custom upsampling of images with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trouble implementing a layer function in TensorFlow. Maybe someone with more experience has an idea how to solve this. The usage of the function should be the following:

In: a `[B x W x H x 2]` tensor called `A`

Out: a new tensor called `B` of size `[B x p*W x q*W]` which is filled like:

```
for b from 0 to B: #loop over batches
    for w from 0 to W: # loop over width
        for h from 0 to H: # loop over height
            B[b,w*p:w*p+p,h*q:h*q+q] = tf.random.normal(shape=[p,q],
                                                        mean=A[b,w,h,0],
                                                        stddev=A[b,w,h,1])
```

What I basically want to do is up-sample an image with "random (gaussian) interpolation".

I fail creating an empty tensor and filling it, as I would do usually according to the pseudocode. What I tried is using TensorFlows `tf.map_fn()` function, which unfortunately didn't work.

The idea is to use this layer later as alternative for mean- or max-pooling.

Maybe there is a simpler way to do this?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a vectorized way (which should be much faster than looping or mapping) like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def gaussian_upsampling(A, p, q):
    s = tf.shape(A)
    B, W, H, C = s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3]
    # Add two dimensions to A for tiling
    A_exp = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(A, 2), 4)
    # Tile A along new dimensions
    A_tiled = tf.tile(A_exp, [1, 1, p, 1, q, 1])
    # Reshape
    A_tiled = tf.reshape(A_tiled, [B, W * p, H * q, C])
    # Extract mean and std
    mean_tiled = A_tiled[:, :, :, 0]
    std_tiled = A_tiled[:, :, :, 1]
    # Make base random value
    rnd = tf.random.normal(shape=[B, W * p, H * q], mean=0, stddev=1, dtype=A.dtype)
    # Scale and shift random value
    return rnd * std_tiled + mean_tiled

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(100)
    mean = tf.constant([[[ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0],
                         [ 4.0,  5.0,  6.0]],
                        [[ 7.0,  8.0,  9.0],
                         [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]]])
    std = tf.constant([[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
                        [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]],
                       [[0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
                        [1.0, 1.1, 1.2]]])
    A = tf.stack([mean, std], axis=-1)
    with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
        print(sess.run(gaussian_upsampling(A, 3, 2)))
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.94  0.97  1.82  1.67  2.89  2.96]
  [ 1.04  0.78  2.23  2.02  2.95  3.04]
  [ 0.9   0.96  1.84  1.98  2.74  3.06]
  [ 3.89  4.12  5.72  4.32  6.02  5.7 ]
  [ 3.47  4.27  4.39  4.85  6.38  5.32]
  [ 3.21  3.98  4.64  4.31  5.72  5.96]]

 [[ 8.15  7.08  7.33  7.78  8.75  9.95]
  [ 7.37  7.29  8.27  8.26  8.56  8.17]
  [ 5.91  7.95  7.9   7.81  8.43  8.64]
  [11.12 11.49 11.95 11.74 11.43 12.3 ]
  [ 9.98  9.66  9.21 10.2  12.78 12.13]
  [ 8.33 10.37 11.88 11.44 12.96 11.73]]]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution works tremendously! Thank you so much!